# Finding the fibonacci numbers in a certain range using python

Tags: python-2.7, fibonacci

I am trying to write a function in python that returns a list of all the fibonacci numbers in a certain range but my code wont work it simply returns [0]. What is the problem?

```
from math import sqrt
def F(n):
    return int(((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5)))


def Frange(x):
    A = [0]
    while max(A) < x:
        H = 1
        for i in range(H):
            A.append(F(i))
        H = H+1
    return A
```

Comment: Please describe in what way it fails, i.e. any errors or what the incorrect results are.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg i have done that any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `H = 1` as the first statement in your `while` loop; so every time you enter the `for` loop, `H = 1` and you'll only get the Fibonacci number for `n=0`

You need to set `H = 1` outside the `while` loop:

```
def Frange(x):
    A = [0]
    H = 1
    while max(A) < x:

        for i in range(H):
            A.append(F(i))
        H = H+1
    return A
```

You could have solved this yourself very easily by printing various values inside the loops, such as `print H`.

Comment: thank you so much, i am new to programming, why didnt i see that?

Answer (score 0):

I found another error and the improved code is:

```
   from math import sqrt
    def F(n):
        return int(((1+sqrt(5))**n-(1-sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*sqrt(5)))

    def Frange2(x):
        A = [0]
        H = 1
        while max(A) < x:
            if F(H) < x:
                A.append(F(H))
            else:
                break
            H = H+1
        return A
```

Comment: There is an "Accept" button next to each answer.   When your question is answered, you click to show that is what helped.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and most popular and uncomplicated solution to calculating a list of fibonacci numbers in a range is

```
def fib3(n): #FASTEST YET
    fibs= [0,1] #list from bottom up
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        fibs.append(fibs[-1]+fibs[-2])
    return fibs
```

This function stores the computed fibonacci numbers in a list and later uses them as 'cached' numbers to compute further.

Hope it helps!